# Search call log in android for a particular phone number

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I'm writing an app where I need to get details of call logs in my android app. Currently, I'm using the below method to get the data

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + " = ?",
            new String[]{custMobNo},
            CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC limit 1;");

    int number = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int type = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    int date = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);

    String phoneNo = null;
    String callType = null;
    String callDate = null;
    String callDuration = null;
    int dircode = -1;
    String dir = null;

    if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            phoneNo = cursor.getString(number);
            callType = cursor.getString(type);
            callDuration = cursor.getString(duration);
            callDate = cursor.getString(date);

            if(custMobNo.equals(phoneNo)) {
                dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
                switch (dircode){
                    case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                        dir = "Outgoing";
                        break;
                    case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                        dir = "Incoming";
                        break;
                    case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                        dir = "Missed";
                        break;
                }

                sb.append("\nPhone Number : " + phoneNo +"\nCall Date : " + callDate+
                        "\nCall Type : " + dir+"\nCall Duration : "+callDuration);
                sb.append("...................");
                sb.toString();
                break;
            }
        }

        cursor.close();
    }
```

Now the problem arises in scenarios where the number stored by the user can be with or without the country code. In such scenarios how do I query? I don't want the complete call logs but the last 2-3 call logs of any number.

I tried using *"in"* query by searching with both, the phone number and phone number with country code but I'm probably using the wrong syntax.

```
new String[]{"+91" + custMobNo, custMobNo}
```

Please tell me how to proceed with the solution?

Answer (score 1):

it might be a late response. But you may do like below:-

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + " = ? OR "+ CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + " = ?",
            new String[]{"+91" + custMobNo, custMobNo},
            CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC limit 1;");
```

If you can not use `in` clause then you may always use `OR` operator.